# Run flash game in headless chrome using puppeteer

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, flash, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

How can I run a flash game in headless chrome using puppeteer? I'm trying to screenshot this [flash game](http://www.bigfuntown.com/Game-59.html) but the game doesn't run and is replaced by "Couldn't load plugin" text.

Here's the relevant code I used to generate the screenshot and its output, running in ubuntu on windows subsystem linux:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({width: 1243, height: 882});
  await page.goto('http://www.bigfuntown.com/Game-59.html');
  await page.screenshot({path: 'game.png'});

  await browser.close();
})();
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In modern Chrome versions flash is blocked by default and requires user interaction to be enabled.

As this was problematic to automate I've made [a puppeteer wrapper](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra) for this purpose: `puppeteer.setExtra({allowFlash: true})`

Note that `headless: false` is still required due to puppeteer limitations.